# How do I resolve Circular Dependency in DI Error: NG0200?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, frontend

This seems to be resolved if I remove HttpClient from PCService and comment out this line:
`return this.http.get<PC>(this.pcUrl + "find/" + id);`

[image]

**main-content.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PC } from '../../models/pc';
import { PCService } from '../../services/pc.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-content',
  templateUrl: './main-content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-content.component.scss']
})
export class MainContentComponent implements OnInit {

  pc!: Observable<PC>;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: PCService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params =>
      { const id =  params['id'];
      this.pc = this.service.getPCById(id);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**pc.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PC } from '../models/pc';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PCService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

 readonly pcUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pc/';

  getPCById(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<PC>(this.pcUrl + "find/" + id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added `HttpClientModule` in your `NgModule` imports?

Comment: Yes, I have another service that is set up the same way and functions correctly.

Comment: can You create a code sandbox to replicate the error

Comment: I believe I encountered this error once when I had a Rxjs version not matching the transitive Rxjs Version imported by Angular. Might want t take a look at your package json.